# Extension of measures in the real plane

Tags: measure-theory, spectral-theory

Can a non negative function $\mu$ defined in the Borel rectangles on the real plane be extended to a measure? Paul Halmos claims so in his book *Introduction to Hilbert Space and the Theory of Spectral Multiplicity* [proof of the spectral theorem for normal operators]. Refining my question, the Borel rectangles are an *elementary family*, and the $\sigma$-algebra generated by them is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel in the real plane, how do you extend this function to a measure in this $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: maybe caratheodore theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem

Comment: I thought about it, but the $\sigma$-algebra is restricted to the outer measurable sets, is this the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a countably additive function $\rho$ on an elementary family $\mathcal{E}$ such that $\rho(\emptyset)=0$, there exists a unique premeasure $\mu_0$ defined on the algebra $\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{E})$ generated by $\mathcal{E}$. Then define an outer measure $\mu^*$ via
$$
\mu^*(A) := \inf\left\{\sum_1^\infty\mu_0(E_j) : E_j\in\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{E})\ \text{and}\ A \subseteq \bigcup_1^\infty E_j\right\}
$$
and apply Carathéodory's theorem to get a measure $\mu$ whose measurable sets include $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ and $\mu(E)=\mu^*(E)=\mu_0(E)=\rho(E)$ for every $E\in\mathcal{E}$.

Then you just have to see that $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ is the collection of Borel sets in the plane. This follows from the fact that every open set is in $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$, as every open set is a countable union of open rectangles.

Comment: How do you know there exists the pre-measure $\mu_{0}$?

Comment: @GideonGlaucus I'm looking through my old measure theory notes at the moment. We define $\mu_0$ on $\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{E})$ by 
$$ \mu_0(E) = \sum_{k=1}^n\rho(A_k),$$
if $E=\sqcup_{k=1}^n A_k$, where $A_k\in\mathcal{E}$. Then we show that this is well-defined, finitely additive, and finally countably additive.

Comment: I assume the $A_{k}$'s are disjoint, right? what's the argument used to prove $\sigma$-additivity? it seems $\mu_{0}$ needs to have a sort of continuity property I'm not seeing.

Comment: @GideonGlaucus Yes they are disjoint. We write $E=\sqcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, with $E_n\in\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{E})$ and consider two cases: one with each $E_n\in\mathcal{E}$ and the other without this restriction.

For the first case, denote $A_k:=E_k$ and note that $A_k=\sqcup_{n=1}^\infty A_k\cap E_n$. Then use countable additivity of $\rho$.

For the second case, write each $E_n$ as a disjoint union of elements in $\mathcal{E}$, and then apply the first case.

Comment: But how do I build $\rho$ in such a way that it is $\sigma$-additive? I have a clear definition of $\rho$ when the argument is a rectangle, but a countably union of rectagles may or may not be a rectangle, it it isn't I could just define
$$ \rho(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} R_{j}) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \rho(R_{j})$$
where the $R_{j}$'s are Borel rectangles.
But if the union is rectangle, how do I prove $\rho$ is well-defined?

Comment: @GideonGlaucus Just to be clear, a Borel rectangle is a set of the form $I \times J$, where $I,J$ are intervals (open, half-open, or closed) in $\mathbb{R}$? In order to show that $\rho$ is countably additive, you need to prove that if $E\in\mathcal{E}$ such that $E=\sqcup_n E_n$, with $E_n\in\mathcal{E}$, then $\rho(E)=\sum_n \rho(E_n)$. This should be easy because you already know $E$ is a rectangle. The map $\rho$ doesn't act on non-rectangles.

Comment: Actually they are what some authors call generalized rectangles, of the form $I \times J$, where $I$ and $J$ are Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$. You're right, the map does not act on non-rectangles and you have to assume the union lies in $\mathcal{E}$, but I don't see how knowing $E$ is a rectangle makes it easy, you at most know $\rho(E)$ exists, don't you?

Comment: @GideonGlaucus "Easy" was probably a poor choice of word. I had in mind the simpler rectangles which are much easier to work with. I'll think about it and post back here if I come up with anything.

Comment: ok, thank you, i will post any further advance.